# Vagrant box cannot be removed - remove command says it's not found even though list command lists it

Tags: vagrant

Hi folks can you advise on why I can't remove any of my boxes, please.

```
$ vagrant box list
base    (virtualbox)
lucid32 (virtualbox)
$ vagrant box remove lucid32 http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box
Box 'lucid32' could not be found.
$ vagrant box remove base http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box
Box 'base' could not be found.
$
```

Initial setup was this:

```
vagrant box add lucid32 http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box
vagrant box add base http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box
```

**Update**
In my original question I wrote the following: <strike>The documentation appears to be very basic and doesn't cover troubleshooting. I looked here:...</strike> etc. I was wrong to say that, it does. Fellow SO user @cmur2 answered pointing out my errors and this was accepted (see their answer below). They provided the fresh pair of eyes I didn't have here. Thanks to them. This question is trivial but I do still feel it is worth retaining in case anyone else has the same block that I had.

Running this on MacOS 10.7.5, Vagrant version 1.1.5 (latest from http://downloads.vagrantup.com/ )

Reason for removal is that I want to start again fresh, I added too many boxes. I should be able to remove all of the boxes I believe.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The list command shows the provider in brackets, a provider is something like virtualbox or vmware not the URL you got the box from and you have to specify the provider for disambiguation during remove, e.g.:

```
vagrant box remove lucid32 virtualbox
```

Comment: Your answer worked for me, thanks +1 upvote and accepted: issued `vagrant box remove lucid32 virtualbox` got: `Removing box 'lucid32' with provider 'virtualbox'...` then a command prompt (indicating it had completed)
`$` Then issued: `vagrant box remove base virtualbox` and got: `Removing box 'base' with provider 'virtualbox'...` then checked to see no boxes:
`$ vagrant box list` and got `There are no installed boxes! Use `vagrant box add` to add some.` So all fixed.

Comment: The official vagrant documentation does mention the provider. It must be because it is late here and it has been a long day, sorry and thanks, at least you have earned some points for your score :) Thanks for your fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: Is there a way to force remove it for all providers?

Answer (score 2):

I had to type the full name of the box (as shown with 'vagrant box list' in order to remove it. Finishing the command with 'tab' resulted in:
`vagrant box remove ferventcoder-VAGRANTSLASH-win7pro-x64-nocm-lite` while the list command showed `ferventcoder/win7pro-x64-nocm-lite`. This caused Vagrant to give me an error: `The box you requested to be removed could not be found. No
boxes named 'opentable-VAGRANTSLASH-win-2012r2-standard-amd64-nocm' could be found.`

I solved this copying the name from the `vagrant box list` command:
`vagrant box remove ferventcoder/win7pro-x64-nocm-lite`.